Repentance prior to a court conviction
It is narrated:

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The one who repents from sin is like one who never sinned.” And the one who did not sin cannot be punished.

Does this mean that if someone is found guilty of murder or rape, but he repents prior to the trial, he can be let off without any form of discretionary punishment? What if it so happens that the forgiveness prior to the trial was completely insincere or worse yet, there is a great chance that person may commit the crime again?

Not exactly. Your answer includes that if someone is either brought to the court and repents, the punishment cannot be waived, or if the one who is wronged decides not to report it, the punishment isn't sought after. My question has to do with if it is known that someone made repentance prior to the trial, but is reported nonetheless, would the punishment still be applied on him? I ask because according to this article: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/7545/he-has-repented-from-stealing-from-the-kuffaar, it implies that the punishment cannot be sought after.

If the Muslim commits any sin, whether stealing or anything else, then repents before the matter is referred to the judge, then he is spared the punishment in that case, and it is not permissible to punish him, because Allaah says concerning banditry (interpretation of the meaning):

“The recompense of those who wage war against Allaah and His Messenger and do mischief in the land is only that they shall be killed or crucified or their hands and their feet be cut off from opposite sides, or be exiled from the land. That is their disgrace in this world, and a great torment is theirs in the Hereafter.
Except for those who (having fled away and then) came back (as Muslims) with repentance before they fall into your power; in that case, know that Allaah is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful”
[al-Maa’idah 5:33-34]

My answer already states that according to the majority the hadd applies regardless of repentance. Hirabah (banditry) is an exception but even in the case of Hirabah repentance only removes the Hadd and not the rights of the people, hence if the bandit killed someone he would be handed over to the heirs of the victim and they can take qisas or forgive him if they wish, and if he snatched something then he would have to repay the owner unless he forgives him.

So just to be clear, the article I referenced is wrong in this case? Meaning that even if the person is found to repent prior to the trial and the victim or whoever decides to bring him into the court, the punishment is still not waived?

The article is not about the case which you are asking. It is not about murder, it is about theft and rather most of the admitted crimes in the question are petty crimes that fall under Ta'zeer which is different from Hadd. See here and here for answers from islamqa on repentance for murder. Secondly as I said 'majority' ... it should be clear that when a majority is mentioned it means that a minority say that repentance waives a hadd especially for theft see islamweb.

How would this apply to other laws like rape or other forms of assault? If the perpetrator repented prior to the trial and is brought to the court, is the punishment waived by the judge due to his repentance before the trial, even if the victim wants the perpetrator to be punished?
